# xml auto or xml path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, xml

Executing the following query

```
SELECT     AssessmentFileGUID as '@FileId',AssessmentFileTypeId as '@FileTypeId',AssessmentFileName
FROM         rat.AssessmentFile where AssessmentId=17 
for xml path('File'),root('Files')
```

gives me following result :

```
<Files>
  <File FileId="2A23D836-612F-418E-BDE8-F182C5432A0D" FileTypeId="1">
    <AssessmentFileName>File-123213.pdf</AssessmentFileName>
  </File>
  <File FileId="CDA853B9-C587-4365-BAF5-972F8D217BAC" FileTypeId="2">
    <AssessmentFileName>File-343455.png</AssessmentFileName>
  </File>
</Files>
```

---

However I need it in the following format:

```
<Files>
  <File FileId="2A23D836-612F-418E-BDE8-F182C5432A0D" FileTypeId="1">File-123213.pdf</File>
  <File FileId="CDA853B9-C587-4365-BAF5-972F8D217BAC" FileTypeId="2">File-343455.png</File>
</Files>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the column that should act as content as [`data()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510419.aspx) and it should go in the right place:

```
declare @T table (
    AssessmentFileGUID uniqueidentifier not null,
    AssessmentFileTypeId int not null,
    AssessmentFileName varchar(max) not null,
    AssessmentId int not null
)
insert into @T(AssessmentFileGUID,AssessmentFileTypeId,AssessmentFileName,
     AssessmentId) values
('2A23D836-612F-418E-BDE8-F182C5432A0D',1,'File-123213.pdf',17),
('CDA853B9-C587-4365-BAF5-972F8D217BAC',2,'File-343455.png',17)

SELECT     AssessmentFileGUID as '@FileId',AssessmentFileTypeId as '@FileTypeId',
     AssessmentFileName as 'data()' //Change here
FROM         @T where AssessmentId=17 
for xml path('File'),root('Files')
```

Result:

```
<Files>
    <File FileId="2A23D836-612F-418E-BDE8-F182C5432A0D" FileTypeId="1">File-123213.pdf</File>
    <File FileId="CDA853B9-C587-4365-BAF5-972F8D217BAC" FileTypeId="2">File-343455.png</File>
</Files>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but try this

```
SELECT     
    AssessmentFileGUID as '@FileId',
    AssessmentFileTypeId as '@FileTypeId',
    AssessmentFileName as "File/text()"
FROM         
    rat.AssessmentFile 
where 
    AssessmentId = 17 
FOR XML PATH('File'), ROOT('Files')
```

Comment: that gives me 
    <Files>
      <File FileId="2A23D836-612F-418E-BDE8-F182C5432A0D" FileTypeId="1">
    <File>Welcome to HDFC Bank NetBanking-4-12-12.pdf</File>
  </File>
  <File FileId="CDA853B9-C587-4365-BAF5-972F8D217BAC" FileTypeId="2">
    <File>Ipad_safari-File-upload-issue.png</File>
  </File>
</Files>

Comment: sorry bilal for wrong answer, i am not sure about it, but can you please try this       
SELECT     AssessmentFileGUID as 'File/@FileId',AssessmentFileTypeId as 'File/@FileTypeId',AssessmentFileName as "File/text()"
FROM         rat.AssessmentFile where AssessmentId=17 
for xml path('Files')

Comment: thanks! but this worked for me :
AssessmentFileName as 'data()
thank you for trying! :)